# session management - cross subdomains

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have the domain `jdavis.software` and have two sub domains `om.jdavis.software` and `api.jdavis.software`. I'm simply trying to make  an asynchronous (ajax) call from the `om` to the `api` that sets a `$_SESSION` variable, then reload the same `om` page and display the session. I've set the `session.cookie_domain = .jdavis.software` in my php.ini so that session creation is from the same root domain.

**Domains:**

- [om.jdavis.software/index.php](http://om.jdavis.software/)
- [api.jdavis.software/test.php](http://api.jdavis.software/test.php)

**Apache vhost config: (for both sub domains and their relative directories)**

```
 AllowOverride All
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

**api.jdavis.software/test.php**

```
<?php       
session_start();

function test(){
    $_SESSION['test'] = 123;
}
test();
print_r($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

**om.jdavis.software/index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script>            
        var ajax = function(data){
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open((data.method) ? data.method : "POST", (data.url) ? data.url : "/");
        http.send(data.params);
        http.onreadystatechange=()=>{
        if(http.status != 404){
            http.addEventListener("load", data.callback); 
          } 
          else{ 
              console.log("Error: Issue with server call..."); 
            }
        }
        };
        function submitForm(form) {
            var form = new FormData(form);
            ajax({
                url: "http://api.jdavis.software/test.php",
                  method: "POST",
                params: form,
                callback: function(e){
                console.log(e.target.response);
                }
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };          
        </script>       
</head>
<body>  
    <form onSubmit="submitForm(this);">
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The sessions_id's are the same, and when I `print_r($_SESSION)` after I run the ajax call and reload the page nothing prints not even the id...

**Question:** Why aren't the `$_SESSION` variables printing out?

Comment: You need to show us all the relevant code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's literally `$_SESSION['test'] = 123` in my code after authentication is successful, the cookies (session_id) is the same on both however when I `var_dump($_SESSION)` nothing prints out.

Comment: Have you set the session cookie domain to match the subdomains? Do you have `session_start()` before setting/reading the `$_SESSION` super global? Have you googled "php sessions across sub domains"?
 The problem when we can't see the code is that we have no clue what you have/haven't  done and we need to either start guessing or ask about every single thing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah I have that set in a `.htaccess` file set to the root domain `.domain.com` and the session id's match on both sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion of adding this to my `headers.conf` file which will dynamically add the Origin domain on the fly as long is it's in the list.

Basically Apache will listen to origin and if it matches one of the domains in the the regex pattern then `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(om\.)?(jdavis.software|google.com|whatever|domains|you|want)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```